# Finding the intersection of two vector equations

Tags: c++, python, math, graphics

I've been trying to solve this and I found an equation that gives the possibility of zero division errors. Not the best thing:

```
v1 = (a,b)
v2 = (c,d)
d1 = (e,f)
d2 = (h,i)

l1: v1 + λd1
l2: v2 + µd2

Equation to find vector intersection of l1 and l2 programatically by re-arranging for lambda.

(a,b) + λ(e,f) = (c,d) + µ(h,i)
a + λe = c + µh
b +λf = d + µi
µh = a + λe - c
µi = b +λf - d
µ = (a + λe - c)/h
µ = (b +λf - d)/i
(a + λe - c)/h = (b +λf - d)/i
a/h + λe/h - c/h = b/i +λf/i - d/i
λe/h - λf/i =  (b/i - d/i) - (a/h - c/h)
λ(e/h - f/i) = (b - d)/i - (a - c)/h
λ = ((b - d)/i - (a - c)/h)/(e/h - f/i)

Intersection vector = (a + λe,b + λf)
```

Not sure if it would even work in some cases. I haven't tested it.

I need to know how to do this for values as in that example a-i.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution with a python function. v1 and v2 are the position vectors. d1 and d2 are the direction vectors.

```
def vector_intersection(v1,v2,d1,d2):
    '''
    v1 and v2 - Vector points
    d1 and d2 - Direction vectors
    returns the intersection point for the two vector line equations.
    '''
    if d1[0] == 0 and d2[0] != 0 or d1[1] == 0 and d2[1] != 0:
        if d1[0] == 0 and d2[0] != 0:
            mu = float(v1[0] - v2[0])/d2[0]
        elif d1[1] == 0 and d2[1] != 0:
            mu = float(v1[1] - v2[1])/d2[1]
        return (v2[0] + mu* d2[0],v2[1] + mu * d2[1])
    else:
        if d1[0] != 0 and d1[1] != 0 and d2[0] != 0 and d2[1] != 0:
            if d1[1]*d2[0] - d1[0]*d2[1] == 0:
                raise ValueError('Direction vectors are invalid. (Parallel)')
            lmbda = float(v1[0]*d2[1] - v1[1]*d2[0] - v2[0]*d2[1] + v2[1]*d2[0])/(d1[1]*d2[0] - d1[0]*d2[1])
        elif d2[0] == 0 and d1[0] != 0:
            lmbda = float(v2[0] - v1[0])/d1[0]
        elif d2[1] == 0 and d1[1] != 0:
            lmbda = float(v2[1] - v1[1])/d1[1]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Direction vectors are invalid.')
        return (v1[0] + lmbda* d1[0],v1[1] + lmbda * d1[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a Google search for [intersection of lines](http://www.google.ca/search?q=intersection+of+lines) you'll find lots of formulas that don't involve division by one of the coordinates. The sputsoft one referenced from wikipedia has a good explanation of the algorithm.

Regarding your math, you are too quick to divide by *h* and *i*. A solution can be arrived at by postponing division. For example, multiply the equation for *µh* by *i* and the one for *µi* by *h* to get two equations for *µhi*. This then gives a final equation for *λ* that is equivalent to yours, but without the potentially illegal divisions:

> λ = ((b - d)h - (a - c)i)/(ei - fh)

Just multiply top and bottom of your *λ* by *hi*.

Comment: Just came back to this. What if ei == fh?

Comment: Good point. This happens when the two vectors are parallel, which means they have no intersection. (The lines have either no or all points in common.) So you do need to check for this condition, but the check is a legitimate aspect of the problem rather than an artifact of the way you have chosen to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the d1 vector is not parallel (or near parallel) to the d2 vector before your computation.  If they are parallel, your lines do not intersect and you get your zero-division error.

Using your vars, if (e*i - f*h) equals or is near 0, your lines are parallel.

Comment: @aeflash If d1 and d2 are "almost" parallel, but v1 and v2 are also "almost" parallel, the intersection may be found. It's the case of a very flat romboid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The lines are always perpendicular but the direction vectors can still have 0 in them. I could work out other equations for the cases where they are 0 but it would be nice to know if there was a simple way people use programatically.

Comment: Perhaps the fact they are perpendicular can simplify things?

Comment: 've just realised I missed out "g".

Comment: @Matthew Mitchell May I suggest you to update the question with all the relevant info? Also, try to use a crystal clear nomenclature for the components of the problem (i.e. in some comment you mention "lines", and those are not defined in your question)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious I was talking about vector equations of lines. Eg. l1: v1 + λd1 is supposed to be a vector line equation.

I've come up with a solution which may not be the best way but it works.